# Como fazer uma query num serviço AWS RDS através da AWS API?

Tags: api, expressões-lambda, amazon-aws

Tenho um banco de dados no serviço AWS RDS e uma API nos serviços AWS API GATEWAY. Uma das opções de requisição de dados quando estamos criando um métodos é usar outros serviços da AWS.

Pesquisando este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103629/is-it-possible-to-query-an-amazon-rds-instance-directly-from-api-gateway) eu vi que não é possível acessar diretamente os dados do RDS. Para isso teria que usar uma função lambda e passar a query.

Alguem poderia explicar como acessar um RDS através da Lambda da API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que criar um API Gateway apontando pra função Lambda que fará a Query via a sua linguagem de programação preferida, uma dica é criar a função lambda primeiro e depois criar a API, ao criá-la vc já terá a opção de vincular com a função Lambda.

Fique atento à sintaxe do return que a função Lambda precisará obedecer.

Em node.js é mais ou menos assim:

```
  var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
                "isBase64Encoded": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true
         },
    "body": JSON.stringify(returnString)};

};

callback(null, response);
```